# Saltstack/Jinja: How to remove the u' prefix from a list of strings

Tags: salt-stack

This is the salt `config.sls`

```yaml
{% set testval = ["172.16.49.169:5044", "172.16.51.156:5044"] %}

filebeat_config:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml
    - source: salt://filebeat/files/filebeat.yml.tmpl
    - template: jinja
    - user: root
    - mode: 600
    - context:
      logstash_hosts: {{ testval }}
```

When rendered, the host entry looks like:

```
hosts: [u'172.16.49.169:5044', u'172.16.51.156:5044']
```

How do I remove the u' before each string?

I have tried `{{ testval|tojson }}`, `{{ testval|json }}` and `- encoding: ascii/utf-8`

Comment: Can you update the question with relevant content from the `filebeat.yml.tmpl` template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tojson` option needs to be in tmpl file, not `config.sls`

filebeat.yml.tmpl

```
output.logstash:
  hosts: {{ testval|tojson }}
  loadbalance: True
  index: filebeat
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be related to encoding, as I am getting the configuration rendered as expected with the below example.

My `config.sls` state file:

```yaml
{% set testval = ["192.168.1.11:5044", "192.168.1.12:5044"] %}

filebeat_config:
  file.managed:
  - name: /tmp/filebeat.yml
  - source: salt://files/filebeat.yml.j2
  - template: jinja
  - context:
      logstash_hosts: {{ testval }}
```

The `filebeat.yml.j2` template:

```
hosts: {{ logstash_hosts }}
```

Renders:

```yaml
hosts: ['192.168.1.11:5044', '192.168.1.12:5044']
```

**However**

Since the Filebeat configuration follows YAML syntax, we can use the YAML list `-` syntax. We can have a `filebeat.yml.j2` template file like:

```
output.logstash:
  hosts:
  {%- for host in logstash_hosts %}
  - "{{ host }}"
  {%- endfor %}
```

Using the same `config.sls` state, the configuration is rendered as:

```yaml
output.logstash:
  hosts:
  - "192.168.1.11:5044"
  - "192.168.1.12:5044"
```